# Align DIV Html/CSS/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Two fold question. I currently have the top but I want it to look like the bottom?

Also, is there a way to Onclick the dashboard box so an input box shows and I can enter a URL and it loads within the box?

```
 <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <a href="#menu-toggle" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="menu-toggle">☰</a>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="well">
            <h4>DASHBOARD</h4>
        <p></p>
      </div>

  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, for your first Problem the simplest sulution is to add some css:

```
.col-sm-9 {
   float: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For your second Problem you wanna search for "iframe" and do some work in javascript i guess.